# Oracle db: how to get current_time?

Tags: sql, oracle, current-time

Mysql has current_time. What is the equivalent for oracle db?

```
select current_time

current_time
--------------------
15:30:16
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SYSDATE`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS') "current_time"
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: It is converted to string. can it be mapped to java.sql.Time for JDBC?

Comment: Yes. Don't convert it to a string if you want a datetime.

Comment: @Sunnyday: Oracle has no `time` data type.